# python MySQL Fetchone / Fetchall update

Tags: python, mysql, fetchall

I have tried everything for the past 48 hours and have not figured out where I am going wrong.

The cursor.fetchone() works as shown:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
for i in row:
        x = '13.5m'
        cursor.execute("""UPDATE table SET market_cap =%s WHERE symbol =%s""", (x,i))
```

but the cursor.fetchall() fails and says:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1")

Comment: The sintax error is near a parenthesis, but you have not parenthesis in the query (at least that we can see). It may be in the variable i. Could you add a print line (`print i`) before your `cursor.execute(...)` and tell us what it prints?

Comment: It prints the following ('AAL.L',)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that you are passing a `tuple` where `string` is expected. You said in a comment that `i` is `('AAL.L',)`, i think `cursor.execute` is formatting it as a string. Try this:

```
row = cursor.fetchone()
x = '13.5m' # this can be outside the iteration since it's the same value every time
for i in row:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE table SET market_cap =%s WHERE symbol =%s", (x, i[0]))
```